# Click on toast notification bar

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone

I send toast notification to mobile with Windows Phone 7. When I'm out of application I get bar at top on screen with my title and description. That is great.
But how can I handle event when I click this bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a page that the user will be navigated to along with parameters when your app opens via clicking on the toast notification. It's called *deep linking* and you can read about it on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662938%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Howtosendatoastnotification).

The XML that you send should include an additional element called `Param`.

```
<wp:Param>[stuff goes here]</wp:Param>
```

You have three options of what you can supply:

> `/page1.xaml` – Defines the screen to navigate to in the app when the
>   app starts. The string must begin with a "/".
>
> `/page1.xaml?value1=1234
>   &amp;value2=9876` – Defines the screen to navigate to when the app
>   starts, along with name/value pairs of info. The string must begin
>   with a "/".
>
> `?value1=1234 &amp;value2=9876` – Contains name/value
>   pairs of info passed to the default start screen of the app. The
>   string must begin with a "?".

You can then then pick these up in your page like so:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    string strVal1 = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["value1"];
}
```